# Array Input for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, nested-table

I am a newbie to Oracle and this is my first post for Oracle queries.

Below is the existing query which inserts 1 row for each SP call.

I want to make change in the SP which would accept input as array where SAP system would would send the Array to Stored Procedure.

As you observe in SP, the value of ID is incremented each time with the each update. The SP will take this input of Phone and Text and insert the value of ID in sequence wise.The ID is not passed in the input.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DetailsTable
(
    Phoneno IN NUMBER,
    Text IN VARCHAR2
    )
aS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO PERSON.DETAILS(
                           ID,
                           PHONENO,
                           TEXT,
                           COUNTRY,
                           LANG,

                           --PRIORITY,
                           SENDER)
   VALUES (
           DETAILS_seq.nextval ,
           p_phoneno,
           p_text ,
           'RSA',
           'EN',
           'Nest-Payroll');
commit;
END DetailsTable;
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE arraytype AS VARRAY(1000) OF VARCHAR2(100);
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_array (in_array arraytype) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3    FOR i IN 1..in_array.count LOOP
  4      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(in_array(i));
  5    END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_array arraytype;
  3  BEGIN
  4    var_array := arraytype();
  5    var_array.EXTEND(10);
  6    var_array(1) := '1st sentence in the array';
  7    var_array(2) := '2nd sentence in the array';
  8    test_array(var_array);
  9  END;
 10  /

1st sentence in the array
2nd sentence in the array
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

We can use a Type in SQL but it needs to be declared as a SQL Type:

```
create or replace type person_t as object 
    (phoneno number
     , text varchar2(100)
     );
/
create or replace type person_nt as table of person_t
/
```

Use it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DetailsTable
(
    p_array in person_nt
    )
aS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO PERSON.DETAILS(
                           ID,
                           PHONENO,
                           TEXT,
                           COUNTRY,
                           LANG,

                           --PRIORITY,
                           SENDER)
   select DETAILS_seq.nextval ,
           t.phoneno,
           t.text ,
           'RSA',
           'EN',
           'Nest-Payroll'
   from table (p_array)t;
   commit;
END DetailsTable;
/
```